# How to convert a noise spectrum to noise per root Hz

Tags: laser, electronics

I have measured the phase variation of laser and did the FFT to get the spectrum. How can I convert my data to the conventional noise per root Hz form?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking of phase spectral density (PSD)?
Phase spectral density represent the amount of phase fluctuation at each frequency.
Have a look on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density#Power_spectral_density

In those formula if $x$ is the power, you obtain power spectral density and if $x$ is the phase, you will obtain the phase spectral density.